# How to push down my SwiftUI Stack to show correctly my TextField on a message app?

Tags: swift, stack, textfield, swiftui

While showing up my keyboard on a SwiftUI message app, the TextField is going up too much.

What do I need to change to have my TextField shown correctly?

[image: When the keyboard is shown - Stack has blank space]

This is the code I am using:

```
var body: some View {
  VStack {
    //MARK: Users messasges
    List {
      OtherUserMessageCell(profilePicture: $profilePicture,
                           date: $date,
                           message: $message)

      MainUserMessageCell(date: $date,
                          message: $message)

      OtherUserMessageCell(profilePicture: $profilePicture,
                           date: $date,
                           message: $message)
    }

    ZStack {
      //MARK: Chat text field
      TextField(TextFieldName.message.rawValue,
                text: $composedMessage)
        .lineLimit(nil)
        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 5, leading: 16, bottom: 5, trailing: 35))
        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 21)
          .stroke(lineWidth: 1)
          .foregroundColor(.primary)
      )
        .background(Color.white$black)

      HStack {
        Spacer()
        //MARK: Send message button
        Button(action: {}) {
          Image(systemName: ImageName.arrowUpCircleFill.rawValue)
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 26, height: 26)
            .foregroundColor(.mainBlue)
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 4)
      }
    }
    .padding()
    .padding(.bottom, keyboardHandler.currentHeight)
    .animation(.easeInOut)
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like `keyboardHandler.currentHeight` provides wrong value

Comment: You are right, I have to subtract the height of the tab view that is causing this issue.